# Find single post then fetch all its categories and category name Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three tables

Post (id, title, image)
Post_categories(id, post_id, category_id)
Categories(id, title)

I am new to laravel. i am trying to fetch a single post and all categories related to that post. I am successful in doing that but now i want to match those categories id's with the original category table to fetch each category name.

So far this is what i did to get post and all its categories

**Controller**

```
public function edit_post($id) {

    $postID = decrypt($id);
    if(!is_numeric($postID) or empty($postID) or strlen($postID) < 1)
       return redirect('/user-panel/posts');

    $post['categories'] = Post::findOrfail($postID) -> categoriesRelatedPost;
    $post['post'] = Post::findOrfail($postID);
    return view('dashboard.edit_post') -> with($post);

}
```

**Model**

```
public function categoriesRelatedPost() {
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Post_Category');
}
```

The only thing i want now is to match those **category_id** with categories table and fetch category name. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to do the following in your `Post` model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'post_categories');
}
```

If that is not an option you can have a relation on your `Post_Category` for `Category` and do `Post::findOrfail($postID)->categoriesRelatedPost->category;`

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/10) laracast video, it perfectly explains the concept and will help you out.